# Is it ok to modify Vuex state using only the payload argument of a mutation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

For example, could I iterate over Vuex data in a Vue file and choose the data needing updating, then pass the found data to an action, which commits it and then the mutation only makes the update?

The reason I'm unsure about it is because the typical format of a Vuex mutation contains the parameter for 'state', so I assume it needs to be used, and the only way to do that is either by doing all the looping inside the mutation, or to pass indexes to it to more quickly find the exact fields needing changing.

#### For who asked, a code example:

***someVueFile.vue***

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
      arrayOfObjects: (state) => state.someVuexStore.arrayOfObjects
    }),
},
methods: {
    myUpdateMethod() {
        let toBePassedForUpdate = null;
        let newFieldState = "oneValue";
        this.arrayOfObjects.forEach((myObject) => {
            if (myObject.someDataField !== "oneValue") {
               toBePassedForUpdate = myObject.someDataField;     
            }
        })

         if (toBePassedForUpdate) {
             let passObject = {
                 updateThis: toBePassedForUpdate,
                 newFieldState: newFieldState
             }

             this.$store.dispatch("updateMyObjectField", passObject)
         }
    }
}
```

***someVuexStore.js***

```
const state = {
  arrayOfObjects: [],
  /* contains some object such as:
    myCoolObject: {
      someDataField: "otherValue"
    }
  */
}

const mutations = {
  updateMyObjectField(state, data) {
    data.updateThis = data.newFieldState;
  }
}

const actions = {
  updateMyObjectField(state, data) {
    state.commit("updateMyObjectField", data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's alright to mutate state passed in through the payload argument rather than `state`.  Vuex doesn't bother to distinguish between the two.  In either case, it's the same state, and neither option detracts from the purposes of using mutations.

To feel more sure of that, you can ask what are the purposes of mutations and of enforcing their use.  The answer is to keep a centralized, trackable location for concretely defined changes to state.

To illustrate this is a good thing, imagine an app with 1000 components, each one changing state locally, outside of a mutation, and in different ways.  This could be a nightmare to debug or comprehend as a 3rd party, because you don't know how or where state changes.

So mutations enforce how and a centralized where.  Neither of these are damaged by only using the payload argument in a mutation.

Comment: And this is still the case even when the Vuex data is accessed through mapState in a Vue file? (posted a code example) I guess I am not sure whether the mapped data is a reference or a copy, e.g. the same as the data in Vuex or a copy of it... I guess though this certainly means that I can do the looping in an action and just pass the data to mutations for updating, without having to use indexes or anything like that.

Comment: Yes.  `this.mapped`, `this.$store.state.mapped`, and `store.state.mapped` (from `import store`) are all equal references ( `===` ) to the same `state.mapped` object you'd use in a mutation

Comment: Nice!! Thank you and this is great to know!

Comment: My pleasure.  Here's a little demo you can study to prove it:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/Lcz1b98k/

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the demo! It does give only additional assurance, super cool it does work that way! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would do all of the logic from one action, you can desctructured the context object in the action signature like so :

```js
actions: {
  myAction ({ state, commit, getters, dispacth } ,anyOtherParameter) {
    let myVar = getters.myGetter//use a getter to get your data
    //execute logic
    commit('myCommit', myVar)//commit the change
  }
}
```

If you need to do the logic in your component you can easily extract the getter and the logic from the action.